# Влияние преобразования типов на скорость приложения

Tags: c++, c, оптимизация, типы-данных, преобразование-типов

Влияют ли на рантайм promotions и/или остальные conversions? Будут ли такие преобразования выражены какой-то ассемблерной инструкцией специальной?

Например, будет ли работать медленнее код `x + y`, где `x,y` - типов `short`, `float` и т.п.? Или promotions происходят на уровне компилятора и в результирующем коде уже будут нужные типы и так? А что насчёт остальных преобразований? Будет ли медленнее код `(long long) x + y`, например?

Для разных типов используются разные инструкции `mov`, но само сложение одинаково для `short` и `int`: https://godbolt.org/z/ds4sM9. Но разное для `float` и `double`.

Но при оптимизациях одинаковый код генерирует https://godbolt.org/z/ja5h8r.

Comment: Это влияние имеется, но вряд ли о нем нужно беспокоиться, пока не доказано, что программа тормозит именно из-за этого. Есть десятки других вещей, которые тормозят выполнение, и в первую очередь - неверно выбранный алгоритм... Так что просто в качестве напоминания - не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией...

Comment: Если вам это важно - замеряйте время.

Comment: @Harry@HolyBlackCat вопрос теоретический, может это влиять или нет вообще

Comment: Конечно, может. Вычисления с плавающей точкой выполняются одними командами, целочисленные - другими. Что до оптимизации в вашем конкретном примере - то там вообще все посчитано во время компиляции :) Чтоб этого не было - см. https://godbolt.org/z/rob7o4

Comment: @Harry если может, то зачем сделали обязательный promotion во всех арифметических операциях? Это же замедляет код тогда

Comment: Почему - замедляет? Например, с байтами работа обычно медленнее, чем с `int`'ами. И - разве это повышение обязательно? Т.е. если я складываю два `int`а - вы хотите сказать, что они будут преобразованы в два `long long`а?

Comment: *"вопрос теоретический, может это влиять или нет вообще"* Теоретически даже фаза луны может влиять... Возьмите свой компилятор (или несколько разных), и померяйте время с разными настройками оптимизации.

Comment: я только не понимаю, зачем на каждый вопрос заводить нового пользователя....

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я имею в виду будет ли преобразование в итоговом коде выражено какой-то инструкцией или нет

Comment: @Harry в чём разница между `add     esi, DWORD PTR [rsp+8]` и `add     esi, eax`?  С `short` получается быстрее работает и нет никаких инструкций для преобразования, раз они в регистры запихиваются а `int` нет?

Comment: А какая разница может дать по времени  выделить  sizeof(int) или  sizeof(long long) ?  Только в том случаи, если рядом не осталось свободного места для выравнивания. И вообще не стоит обращать внимания на то, в каком случаи замедлит ваше движение капелька дождя...

Comment: ну может человек биткоины майнит и каждый потеряный процент - упущенная выгода.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan в `sizeof` как раз нет преобразований, а мне интересны случаи когда они есть

Comment: sizeof(int) означает "размер типа int".Поставьте это выражение вместо него и читайте снова

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ещё раз, вопрос не про выделение памяти. Вопрос про то, может ли влиять в арифметических операциях (`x + y`) преобразование `short` к `int` например на итоговый генерируемый код

Comment: @tweak берете и бенчмаркаете. Единственно надежный способ. Но скорее всего вы найдете тоже самое, что и остальные - да, влияет. Тогда зачем сделали промоушинг? да просто если бы процессор умел складывать разноразмерые типы, то у него было бы вагон и тележка команд сложения, умножения и так далее.

Comment: Для встроенных типов нет. Может в каком то пользовательском типе эта операция сложная, это другое дело

Comment: @KoVadim инструкции для преобразования специальной нет? Оно выражено неявно в `DWORD`, `WORD`? И в чём разница иметь много операций сложения разных или иметь много мувов разных?

Comment: инструкции есть. на второй вопрос - комбинаторный взрыв.

Comment: @KoVadim какие инструкции и почему godbolt их не показывает?

Comment: @tweak, сузьте немного тему. Например, для начала говорите только о целой арифметике и отсутствии больших массивов

Comment: http://sysprog.ru/post/16 - cwd, cbw. Не показывает - потому что Вы их не видите.

Comment: @avp хотя бы для целых ответ услышать для начала. А массивы ни при чём тут вроде бы

Comment: @KoVadim не вижу в смысле они там есть, но я их не вижу? Сделал ctrl+F по этим инструкциям и не нашло ничего

Comment: не видели, потому что не знали, как они называются. Но ещё есть компилятор, который умеет хорошо избегать неудобного ему кода. А ещё есть к примеру movsx.

Comment: @tweak, на практике (в большинстве распространенных чипов) для целых разницы не будет, поскольку предвыборка из кэша идет широкими словами, а дальше все регистровые операции параллелятся. Массивы же очень даже при чем, поскольку тут речь пойдет о предвыборке в кэши и распределении RAM по контроллерам

Comment: @avp зачем тогда вообще нужен тип `short` если в итоге читаем его в `DWORD` и дальше работает как с интом? Ни памяти не экономит, а скорость такая же или хуже за счёт cwd, cbw

Comment: @tweak, short как раз экономит память. Скажется на больших массивах и операциях с устройствами (скажем, по сети)

Comment: @avp но ведь его читать широкими словами надо, как вы сами сказали

Comment: @tweak, широким словом читаются все рядом лежащие данные, выровненные на границу такого слова, даже к которым не было обращения (еще не запланировано, а может они и не понадобятся)

Comment: @avp ок, спасибо

Comment: теперь только осталось выяснить, зачем tweak и клоны это все выясняют.

Comment: @KoVadim, наверное ему в самоом деле это интересно, но работать с основного имени страшно

Comment: вот тоже думаю. просто с одной стороны как будто ничего не понимает, но если прижать, то сразу вываливает нетривиальные данные. либо в паралель на другом форуме сидит

Comment: @KoVadim, еще может здешний контингент испытывает, стоит ли ему с нами общаться. Гипотез можно разных навыдумывать -)

Comment: такая теория у меня была - мол это новый вид HR:) сильно похоже на собеседование. Но я бы хотел бы устроится на такую работу, что бы уволить такого собеседуемого.